# Can I kill these creatures without a ranged weapon?

Tags: xbox-one, how-to-survive

It is currently night time in my game, and I don't have any ranged weapons.   However, I really want to kill one of those fast creatures that only come out at night and hate the light.   Can I actually kill them?  I have to have a torch out to keep them away but when I chase them, they run away due to my torch.  I can get really close, but when I swing, they just get away.

Is it possible to kill them without a ranged weapon?

Should I just put away my torch (so they charge me) and (try to) hold my ground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out this morning that you can indeed kill them, but it was difficult chasing them down.  I was able to corner one of them and kill them with the torch.   However, it started to rain the following night, which put out my second torch.  That forced me to use a flashlight and it was much easier to kill them as I could lure them in.  They provided addition XP once killed.